# How can I update a request CookieCollection after after removing/deleting a cookie object from the collection in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, server, httpcookiecollection

I am having problems working with request cookies on my project. I have a cookie collection with about 3 values a, b, and c.
Then I try the following for instance:

```
$cookieCollection = $this->getRequest()->getCookieCollection();
if ($cookieCollection->has('b')) {
    $cookieCollection->remove('b');
}
```

After doing this the ‘b’ is removed only from this instance:

`$cookieCollection`.

But it is still there in

```
$this->getRequest()->getCookieCollection();
```

Now how do I update the CookieCollection so that ‘b’ will no longer exist anywhere in the entire site?

Answer (score 0):

Request objects are immutable, and so are cookie collections (and responses for that matter). You'd have to assign a new request object with the new cookie collection, like:

```
// ...
$cookieCollection = $cookieCollection->remove('b');
$this->request = $this->request->withCookieCollection($cookieCollection));
```

And if you need this to be available everywhere, then I'd suggest considering to remove the cookies at middleware level:

```
function (\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request, $response, $next) {
    $cookies = $request->getCookieParams();
    if (isset($cookies['b'])) {
        unset($cookies['b']);
        $request = $request->withCookieParams($cookies);
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Cookie Collections](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cookie-collections)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Common Mistakes with Immutable Responses](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#common-mistakes-with-immutable-responses)**
- **[Cookbook > Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Middleware > Creating Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#creating-middleware)**